# ADF: fail to operate IN in view criteria

Tags: java, oracle-adf

The where clause which contains IN operation should be like: Id in ()

For example, where Id in (1,2,5,8)

My code as follows,

```
ViewCriteria vc = vo.createViewCriteria();
ViewCriteriaRow vcRow = vc.createViewCriteriaRow();
ViewCriteriaItem vci = vcRow.ensureCriteriaItem("Id");
ArrayList<ViewCriteriaItemValue> valueList = new ArrayList<ViewCriteriaItemValue>();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   valueList.add(new ViewCriteriaItemValue(vci, values.get(i), false, false, i)); 
}
vci.setOperator(JboCompOper.OPER_IN);
vci.setValues(valueList);
vci.setConjunction(vcRow.VC_CONJ_AND);
vcRow.add(vcRow);
```

Debugging shows that the values have been set to vci but the results show it applies only the first value to Id.

Can anyone help with this?